# Is there a 12V stable output regulator for liion?

Tags: lithium-ion

I need 12V for my system and I want to use 18650 cell. Problem is, that everywhere I looked, only boost converters are sold, which only multiply input voltage.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to take the voltage from a single cell, around 4V, and somehow get 12V **without** multiplying the input voltage or using a boost converter? Why don't you want to use a boost converter?

Comment: Well I do not want output to change because different input. I want stable 12v no matter battery level

Comment: How much current your system consumes?

Comment: Well I'll use more that one cell connected parallely, so I'll get 12V 3-4amps

Comment: You should do a search for questions about connecting these cells in parallel. It can be quite dangerous.

Comment: What system are you powering? Although it may indicate 12V it will probably have a range of voltages that are acceptable - most electrical and electrical items do not expect the input voltage to be exactly the specified voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> Well I do not want output to change because different input. I want stable 12v no matter battery level

You can generate 12 V from boost regulator, even if the input voltage is varying.

---

Boost regulators generate output based on the set feedback voltage. It is not dependent on a integer multiple of input voltage.

There are dedicated boost regulators for single lithium ion cell batteries whose output can be set anywhere from 5V to 18 V. You can start searching from [here](http://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/step-up-boost/products.html#p238min=2;4.5&p238max=1.8;40)..

Please study about basics of buck and boost regulators too. There are many simple application notes and documents on it.

Comment: ok, so as I understand I need to look for boost regulator, not converter. Thanks

Comment: Can you send the link where you read about boost converter?

Comment: well I used few and they simply multiplied input voltage, so output was different. Also in forums read about same thing happening for others.

Comment: There are circuits which multiplies the input such as voltage multipliers.. boost converters are the switching regulators where with the aid of an inductor the energy gets stored and the voltage gets added up to the needed level using a switcher.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that most boost modules do regulate the voltage, they have adjustable output voltages which is why the vendor claims a range of voltages.